# Any languages use the '=>' and '=<' operators?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax, operators

I'm just curious if there are any programming languages that use the '=>' and '=<' operators for something.

I wonder why these are not commonly used when their variant '<=' and '>=' are so widely used by most languages.

Is there a reason why?

EDIT: I'm not asking why they aren't used for the same task as '<=', but why the operators go unused for anything.

Comment: My guess is that it is because you say "less or equal than" in English, so it is more natural to write the corrisponding symbols on the keyboard.

Comment: because that would be confusing, it is easier to have only 1 variant than have to do a coinflip each time you need one

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij true, but my question is broader than just logical comparison. Those operators seem to not be used for anything.

Comment: I use => all the time when doing .net stuff... but I do not think it means what you think it means

Comment: @DrakeClarris **that's inconceivable**.

Comment: Haskell uses `=>` for type class constraints. Though that's probably not an "operator" ;)

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: I've never heard a native English speaker say *less or equal than*, always *less than or equal*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark that's because *equal than* isn't proper grammar. *less or equal to* would be proper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**About =>**

C# does.
Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx

As [MichaelT](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40980/michaelt) commented, it is used as a [Fat comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma). From Wikipedia:

*It is primarily associated with PHP, Ruby and Perl programming languages, which use it to declare hashes. Using a fat comma to bind key-value pairs in a hash, instead of using a comma, is considered an example of good idiomatic Perl. In CoffeeScript, the fat comma is used to declare a function that is bound to this.*

PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Rails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969900/ruby-on-rails-what-does-the-symbol-mean

**About =<**

Prolog uses it as a comparison operator http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#comparison

Comment: @MathewFoscarini both symbols are used in programming languages. Take a look at my modified answer.

Comment: The php and ruby use of `=>` likely comes from the perl [fat comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma)

Comment: @MichaelT thank you! I have modified my answer adding infos about fat comma.

Answer (score 7):

C# (and others) use `=>` as a function declaration token.

The alternatives are used because when spoken it's always "Less than or Equal to" or "Greater than or Equal to" not "Equal to or...".

Comment: oh right, `()=>{....}` it's hard to remember that when you look just as the operator `=>`

Comment: and after C#, coffeescript, and then ES6/Harmony had picked fat arrow syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Scala and ML use **`=>`** in pattern matching.

Scala Example :

```
x match {
  case 1 => "one"
  case 2 => "two"
  case _ => "many"
}
```

ML Example:

```
case shape
of Circle (_, r) => 3.14 * r * r
 | Square (_, s) => s * s
 | Triangle (a, b, c) => heron (a, b, c)
```

Haskell uses it for class constraints :

```
(Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool  -- type a should be a member of the Eq typeclass
```